# How to AWS Route Load Balancer from HTTP to HTTPS for TOMCAT Server

Tags: http, amazon-ec2, tomcat8, amazon-elb

I have JAVA REST API Web Server on Tomcat Server which is running on port 8080 in the AWS EC2 instance.

And There is a Classic Load Balancer to manage all traffic for this instance. So before, ELB was on the HTTP and after sometimes, it was routed from **HTTPS(443: ELB Port)** to **HTTP(8080: Instance Port)** on the Listeners of the ELB.

And I added inbound rule in the security groups of ELB for **HTTPS(443)**.

[Elastic Load Balancer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcKQC.png)

[Security Group of Elastic Load Balancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbyum.png)

When I call HTTP request, response is received but when I call HTTPS, it says **Could not get any response**.

And I added some Web UI to check, that shows for both the HTTP and HTTPS Request but https shows like **line-through(HTML type) the https** and **Not Secure** in the URL Address Bar.

Answer (score 0):

check if 443 port is open for the ELB. Go to Security Groups on EC2 console and ensure the ELB security group has port 443 open.

open HTTPS 443 port on EC2 security group

Comment: I have already mentioned in the question about the ELB port and I have also open the port at EC2 but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a rule set in Ec2 security group which allows inbound traffic on port 443 and port 80 from source ELB security group. If you do not have such rule try adding one and then check again.

Comment: I have already opened these two ports: 443 and 80 for the EC2 Instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened the ports - 80and443 on both the ELB and EC2 sides. Now it is working.